# Answer phone call and hang up phone call within the application?

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

I want to be able to answer a phone call and hang up the phone call as soon as it starts ringing within my application without having to touch the phone. I have searched but I haven't found much about this. Can some one please help?

Comment: Why would your app even want to do this. It should always be the user who is in control of the phone and it is for that very reason that I would not expect there to be a software hook for hanging up the phone.

Comment: is is a way of call blocking  there is code just not well explaind

Comment: here is a link to a more described question of the same http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320046/answer-phone-call-and-hang-up-phone-call-within-the-application

Comment: Robert Massaioli: "It should always be the user who is in control of the phone". What a dumb response. Ever heard of apps that are designed for handicapped people? Please take up a different profession, something more like philosophy.