# Can anyone give me a clear idea about ITelephony.aidl?

Tags: android

I'm a beginner in android.Can anyone give me a clear idea about `ITelephony.aidl` and how it can be used for blocking a call in Android?

Comment: Yes ITelephony could be blocking calls in android. Here are some references that might be helpful to you: [Related SO Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320046/how-can-i-answer-a-phone-call-and-hang-it-up) or [Blog About Android Call Control](http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.com/2010/09/call-control-in-android.html) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new package com.android.internal.telephony in your src folder 
then create a new file (not class) in it with name ITelephony.aidl
paste this body in your file

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;

import android.os.Bundle;
    interface ITelephony {
        boolean endCall();
     void dial(String number);
    void answerRingingCall();
    }
```

then you will see in your gen folder a new package with an Itelephony.java name is created
and now your all problems get resolved

Comment: @vipin, ITelephoy.java isn't generating in the gen folder. Anything I can do to force the generation?

Answer (score 0):

*ITelephony.aidl* is a file that is use to intract with telephony related stuffs, such as auto call pick up, call end. Structure of the *.aidl* file is

```
package com.android.internal.telephony;

import android.os.Bundle;
    interface ITelephony {
        boolean endCall();
     void dial(String number);
    void answerRingingCall();
    }
```

As you can see it have method `endCall()` whish is used to end incoming call dynamically or grammatically so as the other method do their tasks according to their name

Answer (score 0):

`ITelephony.aidl` is not part of the Android SDK. It may be different on older versions of Android, newer versions of Android, or current versions of Android modified by device manufacturers or creators of modded ROMs. Google has advised, on many occasions, that developers stick to the Android SDK.