# android - not getting the phone number

Tags: android, telephony

I'm trying to get the phone number using below code,

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
phoneImei = tm.getDeviceId();
phoneNo = tm.getLine1Number();
```

but, it returns me null value. When I checked the setting, phone number was unknown. I'm using galaxy nexus. Any idea how i can solve this.?

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code :

```
 import java.lang.reflect.Method;

 import android.app.NotificationManager;
 import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.database.Cursor;
 import android.media.AudioManager;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;

 import com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephony;

  public class BlockBlackListIncomingNumber extends BroadcastReceiver {
 private Context cont;
 private Transactions transactions;
 private ITelephony itelephony;;

 int i = 1;


    /* When any incoming calls come to our cellphone number */
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
            {
    transactions = new Transactions(context); 
                // Create an object of transaction class.
    this.cont = context; 
                 // Refer to current object of Context.
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras(); 
                 // Getting Bundles in extras.
    String iNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER); 
                 // Getting Incoming Number by which call comes that’s why we used TelephoyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER.
```

iNumber will be incoming number.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: do you have SIM in your device ?

Comment: do you have GSM SIM because [getLine1Number()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getLine1Number()) Returns the phone number string for line 1, for example, the MSISDN for a GSM phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing ITelephony interface using AIDL

Comment: And this will work on all versions of Android? Is this part of the SDK?

Comment: I guess so, I have implemented it way back ago on Android 2.2. Kindly test on latest versions and let us know your findings.

Comment: I don't think that you are right. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9034931/1525300.

Answer (score 0):

In some countries you will not get the telephone number using your 
code

TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
phoneImei = tm.getDeviceId();
phoneNo = tm.getLine1Number();

You will have to get it input from the user. However to verify that number, you will need to include a send SMS and Receive SMS permission in the manifest file.

Using the sender and receiver's number and the crypted message(which you composed/coded) for verification, you can verify the user's telephone number. Whatsapp does it this way.

Answer (score 0):

> If you are not getting line number you can use this code

```
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    List<SubscriptionInfo> _sb = SubscriptionManager.from(getApplicationContext()).getActiveSubscriptionInfoList();
                    for (int i = 1; i < _sb.size(); i++) {
                        SubscriptionInfo info = _sb.get(i);
                        Log.d("phone", "Mobile_number " + info.getNumber());

                    }
                }
```