# Android - On click hangup outgoing call

Tags: android, onclick, call

I am writing a code to customize outgoing call screen. I have successfully shown my activity on outgoing calls which overrides default android UI using broadcast. Now I want to set some buttons on my screen to **hangup call**, make a call on hold etc etc.

Is there any way I can trigger those buttons which are default in android outgoing call screen, or some good way to make action on them?

My code so far:

```
endCall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.end_call);
endCall.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Hang Up Call
    }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I answer a phone call and hang it up?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320046/how-can-i-answer-a-phone-call-and-hang-it-up)